# Intent.ACTION_CALL is ignoring '#' in android

Tags: android, phone-call

I am trying to call from my application with the following format.

```
AcessNumber,CalleeNumber#
```

Trailing `#` reduce the dtmf trigger duration. But it's not working(making a call works but reducing delay doesn't work). If I call from native `phone app` with the same `format` it works every time. I triple checked my code and it's definitely adding trailing `#`.

```
final Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("tel:");
buffer.append(accessNumber);
buffer.append(",");
buffer.append(number);
buffer.append("#");
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(buffer.toString());
startActivity(callIntent);
Log.e("caller number", callIntent.getData().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really common problem among coders.
The way you gonna have to solve this is by typing this code:
    String encodedhash = Uri.encode("#");

instead of
     buffer.append("#");
use
     buffer.append(encodedHash);

Cheers from Iran

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to me on on this line

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(buffer.toString());
```

If you parse your buffer then it will remove the `#` character try instead like this

```
callIntent.setData((Uri.parse(buffer.toString())+"#");
```

Comment: Log.e("caller number", callIntent.getData().toString()); this line print the line with #. 2nd you can't contact string with Uri i.e callIntent.setData((Uri.parse(buffer.toString())+"#");